# Manim DIsplay Table getting a not defined error

Tags: python, nameerror, manim

```
class TableEx(Scene):
  def construct(self):
      tabla0 = Table(["This", "is a"], ["Simple", "Table"])
      tabla1 = Table(["This", "was"], ["a simple", "Table"])
      g = Group(tabla0, tabla1).scale(0.7).arrange_in_grid(buff=1)
      self.add(g)
```

The output I get is the following

tabla0 = Table(["This", "is a"], ["Simple", "Table"])

NameError: name 'Table' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Title'?

Comment: it's normally because there is no class named Table, but what you mean by Table(["This", "is a"], ["Simple", "Table"]) ? you want to create an array ?

Comment: I'm using manim library [table manim](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.table.Table.html#manim.mobject.table.Table), according to the documentation that´s how tables work, unless im not doing it right

Comment: you can try this `t0 = Table([["This", "is a"], ["simple", "Table in \n Manim."]])`

Comment: still getting the same error, it´s maybe a problem with the manim lib, thanks a lot!
`NameError: name 'Table' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Title'?`

Comment: check if you have the library installed by typing in the terminal `pip freeze` or maybe you forget to import it `from manim import *`

Answer (score 0):

try inserting in the beggining: from manim import *

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).